# What would be the space complexity of reassigning an array again and again in a loop (Python)?

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures, space-complexity

I am working on a problem for which I created a solution, and I was wondering what the complexity of the program would be. We are given an array of digits and our task is to encrypt this array. The encryption follows pascal triangle scheme. That is adjacent elements of array are added and the right most digit of each addition is passed to next step. We need to do this until there are only two elements left in the array.

example:-

[1, 2, 5, 6]

[3, 7, 1]

[0, 8]

we need to return string "08".

Code:

```
def getEncryptedNum(nums):
    
    while (len(nums) > 2):
        crr_level = []
        for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
            encrypt = (nums[i] + nums[i+1])%10
            crr_level.append(encrypt)
        nums = crr_level
        
    return str(nums[0]) + "" + str(nums[1]) + ""
```

According to me the time complexity would be O(n^2) but I am conflicted on the space complexity. I hope someone can help me out regarding that.

Comment: What do you think it is?

Answer (score 0):

The space complexity will just be linear. The line

```
nums = crr_level
```

causes the previous `nums` array to be released (except the first one because it may still has a reference in caller). So you will have at most in memory:

- the original list if it has a reference in caller
- the current (temporary) `nums` list
- the (next temporary) `crr_level` list

less than 3 times the original list.

---

BTW it would be more Pythonic to build the new list that way:

```
while (len(nums) > 2):
    nums = [(nums[i] + nums[i+1])%10 for i in range(len(nums) - 1)]
```

It has the same complexity, but building a list as a comprehension is more efficient that repeatedly adding one element at a time

Comment: Could be a bit *more* than 3 times the original list, due to the extra space for overallocation and reallocation.

Comment: Your list comp doesn't look Pythonic to me, certainly not like "the" Pythonic way. I'd say that's `[(a + b) % 10 for a, b in pairwise(nums)]` in Python 3.10+ or `[(a + b) % 10 for a, b in zip(nums, nums[1:])]` before.

Comment: @KellyBundy: thanks for the comments. You are right, your expressions are much more Pythonic :-). I just wanted to focus on the comprehension point. For the space complexity, what I meant is that there will never be more than 3 lists in memory at the same time and that will not be longer than the original one. Of course various memory can be used for *house keeping* purposes.

Comment: Doesn't feel right to disregard the "house keeping" memory, but, well, doesn't matter for the question. Linear anyway. More interesting question would be how to solve it optimally. I think we can do it in O(n) time and O(1) space.

Comment: @KellyBundy: I fully agree with you including the O(n) time and O(1) space complexity. The algo would be slightly more complex because it will require to handle a multiplication coefficient per element,, but it would be much more efficient.

Comment: Sounds like we have the same idea :-). I've coded it now and it would be O(n) time and O(1) space if my coefficients weren't still the normal ones and thus grow beyond O(1). I have an idea for keeping them small, but it's not trivial and it's bed time...

Comment: So... currently I think it's O(n log n) time and O(log n) space. And for an input list of 2000 digits, it's already over 100 times faster than the OP's.

Comment: @KellyBundy: the coeffs are the binomial coefficients so they can be computed directly. It can indeed be done in O(1) space and O(n) time... Good night anyway :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy: Possible code: ```def binom(lst):
    def val(sub):
        n = len(sub) - 1
        c, p = 1, 1
        v = 0
        for i, e in enumerate(sub):
            v = (v + e * c) % 10
            c = c * (n - i) // (i + 1)
        return v
    return '{}{}'.format(val(lst[:-1]), val(lst[1:]))
```
`binom((1, 2, 5, 6))`  correctly gives
`'08'`

Comment: Yes, binomial coefficients. But they grow beyond O(1) space and thus their operations also grow beyond O(1) time. Anyway, I did it now, keeping all numbers O(1) small (well, technically O(log log n) small). Solves a list of a million digits in 1.4 seconds with ~300 bytes.

Comment: Ugh, not O(log log n) but O(log n). But for practical purposes, where we usually call 32-bit or even 64-bit ints O(1), let's just call it O(1). Your solution looks like my earlier one (so your `c` grows too large), except your list slices still cost linear space. Tested my optimal solution with *two* million digits as well now, takes 2.8 seconds and ~300 bytes, as expected.

Comment: After some optimizations, it solves a million-digits list in 0.8 seconds and 235 bytes (tracemalloc peak). Are you trying it as well (keeping your `c` small), or are you content with the one in your comment?

Comment: Actually my earlier one wasn't O(n log n) time and O(log n) space but only O(n^2) time and O(n) space. And so is your above `binom`. Because of the coefficients being O(n) large. For a list of a million digits, yours would probably take about 15-20 minutes.